# Laravel unique validation fails on update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.7 and using form request but i have a unique branch_name in my database as well as unique slug but every time on update valdiation erorr .branch name already exist

```
public function rules()
{

    switch($this->method()) {

    case 'DELETE':
        return [
            'slug'=>'required',

        ];
    case 'POST':
    case 'PUT':
    case 'PATCH':
        return [
            'branch_name'=>'required|max:255|unique:branches,branch_name,id'.$this->id,
            'branch_address'=>'required',

        ];
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

and also i tried the following but no use

```
'branch_name'=>'required|max:255|unique:branches,branch_name,'.$this->id,
```

and

```
'branch_name'=>'required|max:255|unique:branches,branch_name,slug'.$this->slug,
```

also i have a hidden value for both id as well as for slug even i printed in on rule method i can see id and slug

Comment: there are two column one is branches and other is branch_name what is this?

Comment: @Gurpalsingh.branches is table name

Comment: ```'branch_name'=>'required|max:255|unique:branches,branch_name,'.$this->id.',id'```

Comment: Is `$this->id` equals to the id of the column you want to update in database ?!

Comment: @MohamedEmad.yes you are correct its primary key

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
 use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

'branch_name' => [
    'required|max:255',
    Rule::unique('branches')->ignore($this->route('branch')),
]
```

Replace "branch" with route parameter name from your edit route of web.php.

You can use this validation in add and edit both.

if your database field name is different then send the name as the second parameter in ignore function. Like

```
Rule::unique('branches')->ignore($this->route('branch'), 'branchName'),
```

Details: [Laraval Validation unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique)

Hope this helps.

Comment: what does $this->route('branch') means

Comment: Example :     
 Route::post('office-by-company/{company}', 'OfficeController@officeByCompany'); See the "company" route parameter, if you use different route parameter then change accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;


'branch_name' => [
    'required|max:255',
    Rule::unique('branches')->ignore($branches->id),
],
```

Comment: signh .it will fails on new records even if i add already existed branch name also it will insert

Answer (score 0):

> unique:table,column,except,idColumn

The field under validation must be unique in a given database table. If the `column` option is not specified, the field name will be used.

[validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation)

```
'branch_name' => 'required|max:255|unique:branches,branch_name,' . $this->id . ',id',
```

OR

```
'branch_name'=>'required|max:255|unique:branches,branch_name,' . $this->slug . ',slug',
```

Comment: @vision :o i using : https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2018/9/22/c121ca558c5c4b493f88bd2c34bb147b-full.png

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.